# How to read value from partial view in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm coming from an ASP.NET background and have started with ASP.NET MVC so not sure if I'm doing something wrong here or missing some fundamental understanding.

I have a `PartialView` as shown below:

```
@{
    Layout = "master.cshtml";
    ContactForm form= new ContactForm();
    form.Message = "Thank you, we shall be in touch";
}
```

I have my model with the `Message` property but is **not** being set in my controller only in the PV above. The purpose is the `Message` could be different for different forms.

I have a method which sends an email (this is fine and works, send all the fields from the form) but I would like the `Message` to be the one set in `form.Message` to be sent along when the form is submitted.

I read up on `ViewBag` but I think that's a temp value from the controller to the PV.

The code runs and sets the value for the `Message` on initial load which I established whilst debugging.

Once the method to send the email is reached (after clicking a button) all other fields are loaded except the `Message` value set on the PV.

How could I pass the `Message` from the partial view to my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to send the value to the controller, once the form is submited, you must declare a hidden field for this message, bearing in mind that the hidden field must be placed inside the form, in order to be sent to the controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Message)
    
    // Your form content comes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can send your model if you use HtmlTagHelper like this

```html
@model List<Models.MyModel>

@Html.Partial("MyPartialName",@Model)
```

Absolutely you have to send your model from controller like this

```html
public IActionResult Index()
{
.....
....
return View(MyModel);
}
```

you must create your partial .cshtml in Share folder. This is important

Answer (score 0):

person.cs

```
   public class Person{
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public string personName {get;set;}
       public string contact {get;set;}
   }
```

**MVC Controller**

```
    public ActionResult YourMethod(Person){
         //Your Operations
   }
}
```

MainView.cshtml

```
<form action="YourMethod" method="post">
    <input type="text" name = "personName" >
    @Html.partial("PartialExample");
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

_PartialExample.cshtml

```
   <input type="text" name="contact" >
```